# PHP file upload data not inserted into mysql

Tags: php

I have this below code issue it is not inserting data into mysql but uploads the file into destination folder can anybody have any suggestions? Although it does not show any run time errors.

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

if (isset($_FILES['photo'])){

    $target = 'images/';
    if(!is_dir($target)) mkdir($target);
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

    $stnam = $_POST['stName'];
    $stfat = $_POST['stFname'];
    $stdob = $_POST['stDob'];
    $stage = $_POST['stAge'];
    $stgen = $_POST['stgender'];
    $styea = $_POST['stYear'];
    $stadd = $_POST['stAddress'];

    $fname=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['photo']['type'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['photo']['size'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $fname = addslashes($fname);}

    $sql = "INSERT INTO socio (stName, stFname, stDob, stAge, stgender, stYear, stAddress, stPhoto, ftype, fsize, content) VALUES ('$stnam','$stfat','$stdob','$stage','$stgen','$styea','$stadd','$fname','$fileType','$fileSize','$content')";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(!$result){
        echo"data inserted!";
    }else{
        echo"data not inserted!";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) {

        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
    }
    else {

        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

it shows data inserted! The file TEST.docx has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory but no data is saved in mysql except file.

Comment: Are you getting an error in your logs?

Comment: Can we see what is inside your `db.php` file ?

Comment: It shows data inserted because you have that message echoing in the wrong place. `if(!result)` means if your sql failed, then print out "data inserted."

Comment: Anyway, you should use a prepared statement for that query. Moreover, `get_magic_quotes_gpc` is deprecated since PHP 5.4

Comment: Also, ````stgender```` is that intended? or should it be ````stGender````? because that looks off after seeing the rest of your naming scheme of your columns.

Comment: and you should also have the code snippet to upload the file inside the `if` where you check if the sql was successful; that way either the whole upload is successful, or no part is successful (no file uploaded if data could not be inserted)